# Django - Model design for a generic widget table

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I am trying to build the correct design for the following scenario

1. A `WidgetType` class
2. A `Widget` class, from type `WidgetType`
3. Each `Widget` class has some settings, defined by the given `WidgetType`
4. When adding a new `Widget`, I want to be able to choose only the allowed `Setting`.

This is the model I came with:

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    widgettype = models.ForeignKey('WidgetType')

class WidgetType(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class WidgetSettingOption(models.Model):
    widgettype = models.ForeignKey('WidgetType')
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)

class Setting(models.Model):
    widget = models.ForeignKey('Widget')
    key = models.ForeignKey('WidgetSettingOption')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

While this solves my problem, I feel it is not optimum. Since I can't limit the setting's key for only the allowed set of values in the admin form, without customizing the admin-form

And suggestion would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a FK from `Setting` to `Widget`, you could have a `ManyToManyField` on `Widget` to `Setting`, and use the [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) kwarg to limit the choices to the appropriate settings.